# prerender translate3d content outside of viewport

Tags: html, css, web-applications, animation

i want to develop e mobile website with some animations, but there are some render (?) problems.

all transitions are done with classes similar to this one:

```
.move{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    transition-duration': '.25s;
}
```

i got a problem with divs that are outside of the viewport and then slide in after a button has be pressed or something like that. that divs are drawn while they move, but only for the first time. if they later slide outisde of the viewport and then come back again, its very fluently and nice.

i tried give css attributes like -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; & -webkit-perspective: 1000;, but it didnt make any difference. any idea? thx.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue that you described, to create a drawer-type navigation for a website (similar to the way lots of mobile apps work, like Facebook). Haven't found an answer yet.